# How to setup an elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-map-reduce, amazon-elasticache

I am trying to setup a multi node elastic search cluster.Any useful link which i can follow to setup cluster.
I am trying to run a map reduce programe in cluster to find out exact matches .

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, if you just run the executable in two or more machines connected via a network, elasticsearch will somehow figure it out and all nodes will be added to the same cluster. I don't think you have to do anything.

This is the tutorial I've used: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup.html

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a step by step guide on how to setup an EMR cluster with Elasticsearch and Kibana installed using the bootstrap actions mentioned before.

http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx1E8WC98K4TB7T/Getting-Started-with-Elasticsearch-and-Kibana-on-Amazon-EMR

The article also provides basic Elasticsearch tests on the installed cluster.

The bootstrap actions also provide the Elasticsearch-Hadoop plugin that will allow you to run Mapreduce or other Hadoop applications.

Last version of Elasticsearch Bootstrap actions are available here:

https://github.com/awslabs/emr-bootstrap-actions/tree/master/elasticsearch

Answer (score 0):

The only thing to cluster two elasticsearch node is, identical cluster name of elasticsearch nodes.you can find cluster name  elasticsearch.yml file.[you can find the file in config folder of elasticsearch ].The default cluster name is **elasticsearch**.

To change name edit the property in elasticsearch.yml

```
cluster.name: "custom cluster name"
```

Elasticsearch uses [**zen discovery**](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery-zen.html) to find the the nodes in cluster during start up.If the cluster name is identical the elasticsearch ll automatically form the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link.  You need to install the Amazon Powershell but replace the variables in the script for what you want and it should launch a EMR with elasicsearch.

https://github.com/awslabs/emr-bootstrap-actions/tree/master/elasticsearch

Answer (score 0):

you can use kubernetes to create a cluster of elasticsearch nodes running inside docker containers
take a look at
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/examples/elasticsearch